# Postgres jsonb_set multiple nested fields

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have DB table with a jsonb column that has an entity, with nested child entities. Let's say we have:

`SELECT jsonb_set('{"top": {"nested": {"leaf" : 1}}}', '{top,nested,leaf}', '2');`

Which work's fine by updating `top.nested.leaf` to 2.

But what if we wanted to do multiple fields, such as:

`SELECT jsonb_set('{"top": {"nested": {"leaf" : 1}, "other_nested": {"paper": 0}}}', '[{top,nested,leaf}, {top,other_nested,paper}]', '[2, 2]');`

The above does not work and says:

`ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[{top,nested,leaf}, {top,other_nested,paper}]"
LINE 1: ...": {"leaf" : 1}, "other_nested": {"paper": 0}}}', '[{top,nes...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.`

Any ideas?

Comment: I have also tried the following:

```CREATE TABLE test(data jsonb);
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES('{"top": {"nested": {"leaf" : 1, "paper": 10}, "other_nested": {"paper": 0, "leaf": 0}}}'::jsonb);
UPDATE test SET data = data || '{"top": {"nested": {"leaf": 2}, "other_nested": {"paper": 2}}}';
SELECT data FROM test;```

by using the concatenation, which also did not work.

Answer (score 8):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

```
jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb[, create_missing boolean])
```

neither path, nor new value can't have several values. you have to run it twice for wanted result, eg:

```
SELECT jsonb_set(
  '{"top": {"nested": {"leaf" : 1}, "other_nested": {"paper": 0}}}'
, '{top,nested,leaf}'
, '2'
);
SELECT jsonb_set(
  '{"top": {"nested": {"leaf" : 1}, "other_nested": {"paper": 0}}}'
, '{top,other_nested,paper}'
, '2'
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with concatenation as per my comment on my opening question?

Comment: if you want it in one statement, better try `jsonb_set(jsonb_set())`

Comment: Need this in an implementation where the jsonb_set or the `||` concatenation get's buit up by passing a bunch of field's with their new object/value in.

Answer (score 1):

## JSON_SET another JSON_SET's (sub)result

'joson_set' result type is JsonB with the altered value. So you should be able to nest one call into another:

```
SELECT jsonb_set(
         json_set('{"top": {"nested": {"leaf" : 1}, "other_nested": {"paper": 0}}}',
                  '{top,nested,leaf}',   -- <-- path1
                  '2'                    -- <-- new value1
                  ),                     -- <-- returns JsonB
          '{top,other_nested,paper}',  -- <-- path2
          '2');                        -- <-- new value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a bit more elegant and scalable solution and wanted to share.

**Given**: the following complex `jsonb` object inside `tbl.data`:

```js
{
  top: {
    nested1: { leaf: 1 },
    nested2: { flower1: 0, flower2: 0 },
    nested4: { apple: false }
  },
  bottom: { roots: 'lots' }
}
```

**Problem**: need to change values of `.top.nested1.leaf = 2` and `.top.nested2.flower1 = 2` and even add something like `.top.nested3.branch = 1` in one transaction.

**Solution**: This can be achieved the following way:

```
WITH tbl as (SELECT '{ "top": { "nested1": { "leaf": 1 }, "nested2": { "flower1": 0, "flower2": 0 }, "nested4": { "apple": false } }, "bottom":{ "roots": "lots" } }'::jsonb AS data)
SELECT jsonb_set(
    data,
    '{top}',
    data->'top' || jsonb_build_object(
        'nested1',
        jsonb_set(data#>'{top,nested1}','{leaf}', to_jsonb(2)),
        'nested2',
        jsonb_set(data#>'{top,nested2}','{flower1}', to_jsonb(2)),
        'nested3',
        jsonb_set('{}','{branch}', to_jsonb(1))
    )
) FROM tbl;
```

**Result**: only relevant fields changed.

```js
{
  top: {
    nested1: { leaf: 2 },
    nested2: { flower1: 2, flower2: 0 },
    nested3: { branch: 1 },
    nested4: { apple: false }
  },
  bottom: { roots: 'lots' }
}
```

**Explanation**: the keys here are two powerful yet still convenient operations: `jsonb_build_object()` and jsonb concatenation `||`.

- top `jsonb_set()` surgically replaces value of the top-most object field that is going to change with new `jsonb` value
- this new `jsonb` value is constructed from the original value `data->'top'` by concatenating (`||`) it with new object that contains only fields that change with fully reconstructed values. This results in shallow replacement of the fields with same name and addition of fields that did not exist.
- since values of the new object are objects themselves, we use `jsonb_set()` to fully extract those objects and change only related fields inside at once.

P.S.> It's probably worth moving this question to `dba.stackexchange.com` if possible.