# Update jsonb object in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

One of my column is jsonb and have value in the format. The value of a single row of column is below.

```
{
    "835": {
        "cost": 0, 
        "name": "FACEBOOK_FB1_6JAN2020", 
        "email": "test.user@silverpush.co", 
        "views": 0, 
        "clicks": 0, 
        "impressions": 0, 
        "campaign_state": "paused", 
        "processed":"in_progress", 
        "modes":["obj1","obj2"]
    }, 
    "876": {
        "cost": 0, 
        "name": "MARVEL_BLACK_WIDOW_4DEC2019", 
        "email": "test.user@silverpush.co", 
        "views": 0, 
        "clicks": 0, 
        "impressions": 0, 
        "campaign_state": "paused", 
        "processed":"in_progress", 
        "modes":["obj1","obj2"]
    }
}
```

I want to update campaign_info(column name) column's the inner key "processed"  and "models" of the campaign_id is "876".

I have tried this query:

```
update safe_vid_info 
set campaign_info -> '835' --> 'processed'='completed' 
where cid = 'kiywgh';
```

But it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already and explain what the exact problem with that was.

Comment: I have tried this query.. update safe_vid_info set campaign_info -> '835' --> 'processed'='completed' where cid = 'kiywgh';   But it didn't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
jsonb_set(campaign_info, '{876,processed}', '"completed"')
```

This updates the value at path `"876" > "processed"` with value `'completed'`.

In your update query:

```
update safe_vid_info 
set campaign_info = jsonb_set(campaign_info, '{876,processed}', '"completed"')
where cid = 'kiywgh';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. That worked perfectly fine for me.. :) Also, could you please help if I want to update two keys in a single query.. For example, I want to update the value of **"processed" to "completed"**  along with the value of **"modes" to ["obj1","obj2","obj3,"obj4","obj5"]** ..  @GMB

Comment: I tried this query. **update safe_vid_info set campaign_info = jsonb_set(campaign_info, '{876,processed}', '"completed"'), campaign_info = jsonb_set(campaign_info, '{876,modes}', '["obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4", "obj5"]') where cid = 'kiywgh';**.  But id didn't work.. It throws me an error that  **ERROR:  multiple assignments to same column "campaign_info"**

Comment: @SiddhantKaushal See the comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483515 - if you want to do multiple updates in the same statement, you can nest jsonb_set into something like `set campaign_info = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(campaign_info, '{876,modes}', '["obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4", "obj5"]'), '{876,processed}', '"completed"')`. It's not very readable, but it's an option if you absolutely have to get it down to one statement.